# Getting a syntax error in Mysql create procedure statement which comes from the script I have exported from another mysql server

Tags: mysql

The following code generates an error saying there is a syntax error. I couldn't find any syntax error in this. Beside that, it cant have any syntax error since it has been imported in the form of script from another MySql server unless there is an update in the MySql language itself. if the error is due to the version difference, please can someone throw some light on how the code should be in the newer version.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `iterate_day` (IN `p1` TIME, IN `p2` TIME)  BEGIN
  SET @et = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET @currt = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET @lastday = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
  SET @startHour = p1;
  SET @currHour = p1;
  SET @endHour = p2;
  WHILE  @currt<=@lastday  DO

  WHILE @currHour < @endHour   DO
    SET @currHour = ADDTIME(@currHour,'00:30:00');

  INSERT INTO `blooddb`.`appointments` (`Date`, `timeStart`, `timeEnd`, `status`, `client_id`, `app_id` ) VALUES (@currt, @startHour, @currHour, 1, NULL, NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date` = `date` ;
  END WHILE;
  SET @currt = DATE_ADD(@currt, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET @startHour = p1;
  SET @currHour = p1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

The error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

Can someone indicate whats wrong in the code

Comment: Make sure you use the `DELIMITER` directive before defining the procedure.

Comment: Added `Delimiter ;`  before the procedure, stil same error is appearing @Barmar

Comment: The delimiter should be something other than `;`, so you can use `;` inside the function.

Comment: Why do I need to use a delimeter here? and if you could tell what should I use in this case as a delimeter @barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid MySQL thinking the `;` within the procedures are ending the `create procedure`, you need to change the [`delimter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) for the end of a statement. Currently it is `;`. You can set it to literally anything else.

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

The MySQL documentation suggests `//`.

Don't forget to set it back to `;`.

```
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `iterate_day` (IN `p1` TIME, IN `p2` TIME)  BEGIN
  SET @et = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  ...
END

//

delimter ;
```